# Assign button style at runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight

I desined a button in Blend, which gave me this xaml in after the namespace headers.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Fill="#BF4FFFF" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10" Stroke="Black"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

At the runtime, I am generating a button to which I want to aply this style. How can this be done.
I noticed the buttons have `button.Style` property but I am not able to assing the style to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: In code behind of the same control which your style is: `button.Style = this.Resources["ButtonStyle1"] as Style;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your resource dictionary in your code like:

```
button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ButtonStyle1"];
```

Comment: Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Style'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Edited. and I am sure you gonna handle the boundary conditions

Answer (score 0):

I think  Your Fill Color Code Is Wrong . Please Try This Another Code

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Red" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10" Stroke="Black"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding         HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>


 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
      <Button Content="Button" Height="48" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,71,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"  />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The first two alphabets denote the transparency in such a Fill color format. There's no problem with it.